# On conformality of a mapping in a region.

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

My question is that to show the linear fractional transformation
$
f(z)=\frac{2z-1}{2-z}
$ maps the cicrle $ C:|z|=1$ into itself. Also to prove that $f(z)$ is conformal in $D=\{z:|z|\leq1\}$.

First part is easy to prove.As we can see that if we take $w=f(z)$ then
$
w=\frac{2z-1}{2-z}\Rightarrow 2w-wz=2z-1\Rightarrow 2z+wz=1+2w\Rightarrow z(2+w)=1+2w\Rightarrow z=\frac{1+2w}{2+w}$

Now since $|z|=1$, then $|\frac{1+2w}{2+w}|=1$

Let, $w=u+iv$, then
\begin{align*}
|1+2u+i2v|=|2+u+iv|&\Rightarrow (1+2u)^2+4v^2=(2+u)^2+v^2\\
&\Rightarrow 1+4u+4u^2+4v^2=4+4u+u^2+v^2\\
&\Rightarrow3u^2+3v^2=3\\
&\Rightarrow u^2+v^2=1\\
&\Rightarrow |w|=1
\end{align*}

Hence the first part. Now how to show the second part? any help will be really appreciated. thank you very much.

Comment: you already found its inverse and since the inverse is holomorphic on the unit disc, it follows that the function is conformal

Comment: @Conrad, is inverse required to be holomorphioc to be a function conformal? i read that the function should be holomorphic.

Comment: inverse is automatically holomorphic if the original function is, by the inverse function theorem; now here you computed explicitly the inverse ($z=(1+2w)/(2+w)$) and is obviously holomorphic, so no need to invoke the inverse function theorem